# ASP.NET MVC Razor syntax

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Here is what I would like to express by Razor:

```
<b>@parameterMapping.Title</b> (Category: @parameterMapping.Category.Title, Regexp: @parameterMapping.Regexp)
```

But to make it parseable I have to write it this way:

```
<b>@parameterMapping.Title</b> <text>(Category: </text> @parameterMapping.Category.Title <text>, Regexp:</text> @parameterMapping.Regexp <text>)</text>
```

Are there better ways to solve this problem?

Comment: What are the datatypes for each of those properties?

Comment: What error do you get when you say it's "not parseable"?

Comment: @Larsenal: All properties are strings. I get a strange error saying that there is no <div> for closing </div>. If I remove those lines it works okay.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you wrote down:

```
<b>@parameterMapping.Title</b>
(Category: @parameterMapping.Category.Title, Regexp: @parameterMapping.Regexp)
```

Is actually valid in Razor. My guess is that you have all of this in some conditional or iterative statement (`if` or `foreach` etc). In this case you can wrap the whole thing in `<text>`:

```
@if(Foo) {
  <text><b>@parameterMapping.Title</b>
  (Category: @parameterMapping.Category.Title, Regexp: @parameterMapping.Regexp)</text>
}
```

Instead of `<text>` you could use a valid HTML element like `<p>` or `<div>`. This is because by default after the `{` the parser is sitll in "code" mode and needs a markup tag to switch to "markup" mode.

Note that Razor performs tag matching which is why you need to have the whole scope of the `if` statement contained in a tag if you want all of it to be treated as markup. Otherwise everything that's not inside of a tag would be treated as code:

```
@if(Foo) {
  // Treate as code
  <text>
    Markup
    <div>More markup</div>
    @EscapeIntoCode
  </text>
  // Treate as code again
}
```

Comment: @Idsa any tag will do. `<text>` is a magic tag that does not get rendered to the output.

Comment: But according to the code in my question, <b> tag didn't switch razor to markup mode.

Comment: @Idsa I added clarification that should answer your question